# HTTP commit notifications from a Mercurial repository?

Tags: http, mercurial

I would like to achieve a behavior similar to the [NotifyExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NotifyExtension) of Mercurial, except that instead of an email to be send, it would be an HTTP request to be performed on a specified URL.

Does anyone know how to achieve such a behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install a `changegroup` hook in the server that uses `wget` or `curl` to fetch the URL. See the [hook documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) for the available environment variables.